# "Use the echo command and the redirect operator to create a file named “test.txt” whose sole contents are “Hello world”."

Tags: cmd

I encountered this question

> Use the echo command and the redirect operator to create a file named “test.txt” whose sole contents are “Hello world”.

I don't understand exactly what it wants me to do or how to do it. It is required to do before continuing. I've looked at all the questions and this is the only one I don't understand.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework/test for you.

Answer (score 1):

Run cmd, and then type this at the prompt:

```
echo Hello World>test.txt
```